# can't ping google from centos vm

Tags: centos, virtual-machine

Recently installed centos virtual machine (vm player) in my windows 7 host.

- I can ping my vm from internal network without any problem.
- I can also reach internal network from my vm without issues.
- But my vm cant access internet, I can't ping google for example or any other external network.

I tried several solutions, I spent more than a week trying to figure out what's the issue.

Configuration:

- My VM is bridged and working in DHCP mode:

[root@localhost ~]# **ifconfig**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:2F:D7:52  
          inet addr:**172.31.44.128**  Bcast:172.31.47.255  Mask:255.255.248.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe2f:d752/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:15535 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:503 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1099726 (1.0 MiB)  TX bytes:38953 (38.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4098 (4.0 KiB)  TX bytes:4098 (4.0 KiB)
```

[root@localhost ~]# **more /etc/sysconfig/network**

```
NETWORKING=yes

NETWORKING_IPV6=yes

HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
```

[root@localhost ~]# **

```
more /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0**
# Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)

DEVICE=eth0

BOOTPROTO=dhcp

DHCPCLASS=

HWADDR=00:0C:29:2F:D7:52

ONBOOT=yes
```

[root@localhost ~]# **

```
more /etc/resolv.conf**
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script

search dhcp.city.country.company
nameserver 172.31.41.2
nameserver 172.17.25.22
nameserver 172.16.25.10
```

[root@localhost ~]#

```
**netstat -rn**

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
172.31.40.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         172.31.40.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

I can ping my gateway, can ping my DNS and proxy also:

[root@localhost ~]#

```
ping 172.31.40.1

PING 172.31.40.1 (172.31.40.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.40.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=11.9 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.40.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=1.18 ms

[root@localhost ~]# ping 172.31.41.2

PING 172.31.41.2 (172.31.41.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.41.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.75 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.41.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.520 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.41.2: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.580 ms

[root@localhost ~]# ping ptx.proxy.corp.company

PING lmarcproxy100.ptx.fr.company (10.7.80.40) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lmarcproxy100.ptx.fr.company (10.7.80.40): icmp_seq=1 ttl=246 time=40.2 ms
64 bytes from lmarcproxy100.ptx.fr.company (10.7.80.40): icmp_seq=2 ttl=246 time=40.1 ms
64 bytes from lmarcproxy100.ptx.fr.company (10.7.80.40): icmp_seq=3 ttl=246 time=40.2 ms
64 bytes from lmarcproxy100.ptx.fr.company (10.7.80.40): icmp_seq=4 ttl=246 time=40.2 ms
```

Network interface is up & running:

```
[root@localhost ~]# service network status
Configured devices:
lo eth0
Currently active devices:
lo eth0
```

Firewalls are Stopped:

```
[root@localhost ~]# service iptables status
Firewall is stopped.
[root@localhost ~]# service ip6tables status
Firewall is stopped.
```

What else? I can yum also!

But I can't connect to internet!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to ping to your nameserver ip addresses and try to ping to your gateway address. Disable the search... line in your resolv.conf